# I am no king, and this woman, no queen

Tags: punctuation

Just wondering whether the comma after 'woman' is correct in the title. The meaning of the sentence is: 'I am not a king, *nor* is this woman a queen.' The reason I don't simply write it that way is because it's a line for a poem. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's pretty good the way it is.  What the second comma implies is that "is no" has been elided.  (And, of course, poetry gets a free pass anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of the use of the **gapping comma** (ie the comma in its gapping-comma role).

> Commas:  The Gapping Comma
>
> The gapping comma is very easy. We use a gapping comma to show that
>   one or more words have been left out when the missing words would
>   simply repeat the words already used earlier in the same sentence.
>   Here is an example:
>
> *Some Norwegians wanted to base their national language on the speech* 
>   *of the capital city; others, on the speech of the rural countryside.*
>
> The gapping comma here shows that the words *wanted to base their* 
>   *national language*, which might have been repeated, have instead been 
>   omitted. This sentence is equivalent to a longer sentence like this:
>
> *Some Norwegians wanted to base their national language on the speech*
>   *of the capital city; others wanted to base it on the speech of the*
>   *rural countryside.*
>
> Here is another example, which contains both
>   listing commas and gapping commas:
>
> *Italy is famous for her composers and musicians, France, for her chefs*
>   *and philosophers, and Poland, for her mathematicians and logicians.*
>
> (Here I have inserted a listing comma before *and* for the sake of
>   clarity.)
>
> Gapping commas are not always strictly necessary: you can leave them
>   out if the sentence is perfectly clear without them:
>
> *Italy is famous for her composers and musicians, France for her chefs*
>   *and philosophers, and Poland for her mathematicians and logicians.*
>
> Use your judgement: if a sentence seems clear without gapping commas,
>   don't use them; if you have doubts, put them in.

[[University of Sussex_Informatics](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/gapping)]

Here, the sentence

*I am no king, and this woman, no queen.*

is simply

*I am no king, and this woman is no queen.*

with the repeated verb omitted. I'd omit the comma with this example.

Comment: Interesting for the fact that I was 5 minutes ago just discussing Bokmål, Nynorsk, and Gamelnorsk with my wife.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a comma after the *and* and have

*I am no king and this woman, no queen.*

Essentially you're using the comma after "*woman*" to stand in for "*is*" and provide pause and hence emphasis.

Given that it's a poem, you have poetic license.